# Why am I not getting "y_pred" values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I am trying to obtain the prediction set but I think I am missing something in this part.

```
# PREDICTIONS    
y_pred= regression_model.predict(X_test.astype('float32'))
```

The result shows this:

```
   1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step
```

I don't understand. How can I obtain the "y_pred" values?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are passing a single X to test. The result is stored in 'y_pred'. You can:

```
print(y_pred)
```

to display the content.

Comment: I see.. Thank you so much!